# basic search through array

Tags: java

```
Name = Input.next();

for(int K = 0; K < CurrentCount ; K++) {
  if( ArrayList[K].LastNamePlayer == Name)
    System.out.println(
      "Name " + ArrayList[K].GetName() + ArrayList[K].GetLastName());
```

I can access all the values in the array but when I set a condition it returns nothing when it should.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're comparing strings by *reference*. In other words, you're checking whether the references `ArrayList[K].LastNamePlayer` and `Name` are references to the exact same object. I suspect you want:

```
if (ArrayList[K].LastNamePlayer.equals(Name))
```

which will check for string *equality*... whether they're references to equal strings: ones which represent the same sequence of characters.

Note that these variable names are unconventional for Java - normally you'd have `name`, `lastNamePlayer` etc, using camel case instead of Pascal case. Similarly the method name would normally be `getName()` instead of `GetName()`.

Also, it looks like `ArrayList` is an array, not an `ArrayList`, so it's a pretty misleading name. It would be more useful if it described what it *represented* rather than the storage, too.

Comment: @Harry: No, I was just fixing that. All those odd capitals were confusing me :)

Answer (score 1):

Instead of

```
if( ArrayList[K].LastNamePlayer == Name)
```

write

```
if( ArrayList[K].LastNamePlayer.equals(Name))
```